# Запись переменной в id внутри image_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Знатоки! Прошу помощи разобраться в синтаксической проблеме.
Есть у меня в DOM-е такая конструкция:

```
<%= image_tag('play.svg', alt: "Rails logo", class: "play#{index+1}") %>
```

и есть у меня переменная:

```
<%= album_info.album %>
```

Задача. Присвоить конструкции id значением которого была бы данная переменная.

Мои размышления:

```
<%= image_tag('play.svg', alt: "Rails logo", class: "play#{index+1}", id: <%= album_info.album %>) %>
```

выдает ошибку написания.

```
<%= image_tag('play.svg', alt: "Rails logo", class: "play#{index+1}", id: "<%= album_info.album %>") %>
```

выдает ошибку написания.

Как же все таки правильно?

Comment: Я имел ввиду ошибку синтаксиса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кусок `id: ...` уже находится внутри тэга:

```
<%= image_tag('play.svg', alt: "Rails logo", class: "play#{index+1}", id: album_info.album) %>
```

Comment: Премного благодарен, через несколько минут щелкну галочку решенной проблемы.